# Ffmpeg: alternating audio languages in resulting movie for language learning

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pipe

1. Need to convert multiple-(audio)-language-video to single-audio-stream-video where 2 languages alternate repeatedly.
   (10sec Lang2) + (15sec Lang3) + (10sec Lang2) + (15sec Lang3) + ... and so on till the end.
   I assume it should be done with piping in and changing audio streams. (I've read ffmpeg piping documentation but didn't quite understand it).

I've done audio switching task (with scripting on Windows) by lively changing audio languages in video player but need better and crossplatform solution for little kid - preprepared video.

2. If possible, to adjust loudness of one of the input audio streams to the other.

P.S. Think it would be useful for many married (programmers) to show little kids bilingual cartoons. (To prepare for language learning). By balancing 10/15 sec you may retain kid's attention — the older they grow the more native language they demand.

Irrelevant, just for what's my experience:
%ffmpeg% -y -f concat -safe 0 -i %playlist% -i %picture% -map:v 0 -map:v 1 -c:v copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic -ac 1 -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 16000 -%title% -%album% -%artist% %lyrics% -c:a aac -q:a 1 %output%